# Related to open source sip client phone (Peers opensouce)

Tags: java

Iam using a open source code of Peers Java SIP Softphone downloaded from http://peers.sourceforge.net/.

I want to run this application on linux operating system but when iam placing a outgoing call from this application the call established late after creating a connection receiver voice coming late only in linux os.

And when i run this application on windows so the application response proper but for windows i have to use jdk32 bit

Comment: Right now the post is a little tough to understand so make sure to check out [ask] for help on editing your post.